# CakePHP pagination with custom method

Tags: cakephp

I need to implement a custom pagination where one of the fields needs to be populated by a custom PHP method that cannot be implemented using MySQL - ie, I cannot rely on *virtualFields*.

I tried to use a custom find type, capturing the *after* event and populating the custom field but the pagination doesn't work with this custom property.

In practical terms, this is what I do to do:

```
$readers = $this->Paginator->paginate('Reader', array(
  'Reader.account_id' => $this->Auth->user('user_id')
));
```

*$readers* would have a *status* property where it's populated using a PHP method. How can I use this dynamic property and the Pagination component at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Please use these lines

```
$this->paginate=array('conditions'=>  array('Reader.account_id' => $this->Auth->user('user_id')));

$readers=$this->paginate('Reader');
```

Comment: I don't understand what this has to do with my question.. how can I add the custom property to the pagination component?

Comment: please send example for your requirement. I'll help you.